# how to add adding multiple aws target groups to multiple autoscaling groups using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

i am creating 4 target groups and 4 nlb , count is based on number of screenrecorders (01-04). Also 3 ASG one for each AZ. I want to add 4 target groups to each ASG.
for example : fw_asg_az1 should have 4 target groups attached, same way for fw_asg_az2 and fw_asg_az3 same target groups needs to be attached.

in future if i add server05 in my variable and re run terraform, newly created target group should be added to all three ASG's

variables in my main.tf

```
screenrecorders = [
      "server01",
      "server02",
      "server03",
      "server04"  
  ]
```

variable.tf

```
variable "screenrecorders" {
  description = "List of screen recorders"
  type = list(string)
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "fw_asg_az1" {
  name = "${var.deployment_prefix}-asg-${var.az1}"
  availability_zones = [var.az1]
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  default_cooldown          = 600
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.fw_launch_template_az1.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 5
  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "${var.deployment_prefix}-${var.az1}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
  target_group_arns = ["${aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr.arn}"]
  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr]   
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "fw_asg_az2" {
  name = "${var.deployment_prefix}-asg-${var.az2}"
  availability_zones = [var.az2]
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  default_cooldown          = 600
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.fw_launch_template_az2.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 5
  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "${var.deployment_prefix}-${var.az2}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  } 
  target_group_arns = ["${aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr.arn}"]
  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr]   
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "fw_asg_az3" {
  name = "${var.deployment_prefix}-asg-${var.az3}"
  availability_zones = [var.az3]
  #availability_zones = [data.aws_availability_zones.all.names]
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  default_cooldown          = 600
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.fw_launch_template_az3.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 5
  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "${var.deployment_prefix}-${var.az3}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
  target_group_arns = ["${aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr.arn}"]
  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr]
  
}

###############################################################################
#                              ELB Target Groups
###############################################################################
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "tg_scr_vr" {
  count       = length(var.screenrecorders)
  name        = "tg-${var.screenrecorders[count.index]}"
  target_type = "instance"
  protocol    = "TCP"
  port        = "80"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  health_check {
    protocol = "TCP"
    port     = "traffic-port"
    

  }
}

###############################################################################
#                              ELB
###############################################################################
resource "aws_lb" "lb_scr_vr" {
  count              = length(var.screenrecorders)
  name               = "lb-${var.screenrecorders[count.index]}"
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  internal           = false
  ip_address_type    = "ipv4"
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = var.az1_fw_public_subnet_id
  }
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = var.az2_fw_public_subnet_id
  }
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = var.az3_fw_public_subnet_id
  }
}
```

error i am getting

```
Error: Missing resource instance key

  on .terraform/modules/fw/main.tf line 147, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "fw_asg_az1":
 147:   target_group_arns = ["${aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr.arn}"]

Because aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr has "count" set, its attributes must
be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr[count.index]
```

i tried below as suggested in the error, still didn't work

```
aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr[count.index]
```

i am new to terraform, still learning, any help from stackoverflow community is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 target_group_arns = ["${aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr.arn}"]
```

it should be :

```
 target_group_arns = aws_lb_target_group.tg_scr_vr[*].arn
```

if you want to associate all four TFs with a single ASG.